# Wire size for water heater

Tags: water-heater, 240v

I'm installing a instant on demand water heater that requires a 220v - 40 amp circuit and would like to know what size wire is required for a 50 foot run. ??????

Comment: This water heater can be run on 4 different settings.  10, 20, 30 or 40 amp circuit. I'm looking to use the 40 for maximum efficiency

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's best if you edit new information into the question text, rather than posting it as a comment. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are you planning to run a cable (NM or armored/metal-clad), or individual wires in a conduit? How is the rest of your house wired, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

8 AWG copper wire or 6 AWG aluminum. For the ground wire, 10 AWG copper.

Most on-demand heaters need 2 wires + ground, but check your installation instructions to be sure it doesn't need 3.

Keep in mind a 40A on-demand is a pretty small heater and you may need to reduce flow to get hot enough water.